# #gets appended at the end of url on clicking rad tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have uploaded my application to live server published code into iis my tab doesn't works on live,tab gets post back on the local, # gets appended automatically at the end of the url unable to postback on the server which causes the postback working to stop.

Comment: on your page there is href="#" for some control and when u click it which adds # at the end of page

Answer (score 0):

Look for JavaScript errors on your page. If there are, the tab will not be able to execute its JS logic, so it will act as an ordinary anchor and add the hash to the URL.

It is often the case that webresources do not load on your production server because of permissions. Check these two articles for more info on troubleshooting that:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-troubleshooting.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html

You will, most likely, need to let your user access webresource:

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

Also, you can try using the CDN to avoid loading resources from your server: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html. If you have it enabled already, then you may not have connection to the cloud where the scrips come from, so you can consider disabling it.